# Define Apache Camel route URI options to avoid spam

Tags: groovy, apache-camel, imap, apache-camel-mail

I would like to avoid spam when reading from a imap endpoint using Apache Camel.

My endpoint is configured in this way:

```
def camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext()
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    def void configure() {
        from("imap://localhost:3143?username=myuserame&password=mypassword"
             + "&delete=false"
             + "&unseen=true"
             + "&consumer.delay=600" 
             + "&fetchSize=10" 
             + "&maxMessagesPerPoll=10").process{ exchange ->
                ...
            }
```

I would like to add `searchTerm` in order to avoid messages marked with `*****SPAM****` in the subject or having the headers `X-Spam-Flag: YES` or `X-Spam-Status: YES`.

I would also like to blacklist some email addresses but I guess this can do this after having read the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you would need to implement a custom `avax.mail.search.SearchTerm` class where you can filter the mail messages. You can find more details at: http://camel.apache.org/mail.html how to use custom search term class. Also you can check the unit test source code of camel-mail for examples.

Is those spam headers a standard? I am asking as we could consider adding a check OOTB that can skip those mails if they have one of those spam headers.